# Assume that a file containing a single byte, when i read that file with bufferedreader and filereader which will be faster and why?

Tags: java, io

It is known that filereader performs read for each and every byte while bufferdreader take a large quantity of byte and store it in buffer so one read call in buffered reader will fetch more byte and thus it is faster. Now which will be faster if a file has a content of size one byte.

Comment: Why would the difference, whatever it is in whatever direction, be large enough to matter?

Comment: Whatever is going to happen in the JVM will be insignificant compared to the actual physical read of one byte. Besides, the hard disc reads a sector at a time, which is always more than one byte (somewhere around 512 to 4096 bytes).

Comment: You cannot physically read a single byte from a file. That will happen in units of chunks/sectors/buffers/blocks.